# eTag handling for Alamofire image

Tags: ios, alamofireimage

I have read up about ETag handling for Aamofire image here: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/issues/111

The thing is, I want to fetch an image only if the ETag has changed in the response header. In the method af_setImage(withUrlRequest), I don't see any handling for ETag. Do I have to make a separate request just to see if the ETag has changed? In that case I'll have to maintain the previous ETag as well, which I don't want to do, as there are many requests to be made for multiple images.